# Installing trap with new deeper sink

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I am trying to install a trap but I am having issues in doing so. I can seem to get the trap arm to line up with the trap.

I am off by just about half an inch.

[image]

Is there any solution other than lowering the drain that is code compliant?

Comment: Ugh. This exact thing happened to me during our kitchen remodel.  I realized there would always be standing water in the disposal.  It was an outside wall, so I ended up breaking through the stucco and just lowering the drain.

Comment: This just happened with my super deep sink install. My plumber was able to simply cut some ABS and make it fit without any issues (although it took some solid planning). Can you not just go get some more ABS pipe and construct something that fits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **normal solution** to this is to trim the lower end of the black part.

Tailpieces are supplied long, and expected to be trimmed to fit. Of course, there are limits to that.

**In this case**, it looks like the elbow in the black part is going to cause a problem (or be a limit) with that approach. Such is the danger of a deeper sink. You may indeed need to lower the drain entrance into the pipe in the wall, unless you can find a disposer that exits a little bit higher (which would be easier, and possibly cost less.)

Answer (score 7):

The trap seal depth in the P trap should be a minimum of two inches deep and a maximum of four inches - see the diagram below to know how to measure it.

First of all, trim all you can off of the black tailpiece and raise the P trap as high as possible. If you're still not there you might be able to find either a slightly shorter P trap or a slightly longer elbow connecting into the drain.

These drain pieces do have some flexibility in assembling them. Once you get it together check to make sure that you're not too far off the 4 inch max. You also want to maintain a proper slope of 1/4 inch per foot in the drain line from the trap outlet to the wall.

[image]